# Extracting bucket name from CNAME record using Neo4j

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, neo4j, cypher

The CNAME data is stored in node `B.type`.
the value is `s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/test.my-domain.com/index.html`.
What should be the best way to extract the bucket name here(`test.my-domain.com`) using cypher query in the WHERE statement? I tried using [substring](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/string/) but could not eliminate index.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split` function and pick the element at index 1:

```
MATCH (b:B)
WITH b, split(b.type, '/')[1] AS bucketName 
WHERE bucketName = your_condition
RETURN b
```

Here, we are using `WITH` clause to store bucket name in a new variable, so that we can easily use it in `WHERE` clause without recalculating it.

Comment: Thanks for that. Is there a way to get the value with the WHERE statement? I have to compare the extracted bucket name with more values.

Comment: can you help me here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73441384/cypher-query-to-match-a-node-value-against-a-list-of-values

Comment: I saw the question, I don't get it. What are we trying to do exactly?

Comment: generating a list called 'bucket_names' and then checking if 'bucket_record' is not present in 'bucket_names' list.

Comment: both of these are list, so you are basically looking for a list within another list. Is that expected?

Comment: oh that could be the mistake then. bucket_record has to be current node value and not a list. Only bucket_names should be a list of all bucket names.

Comment: The idea is to find a bucket_record that is pointing to a bucket name that is already deleted.

Comment: Added an answer. Try it out